# How do I show a div if a string within it is different using localStorage?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I've created a notification that appears in the bottom-right side of the screen for new blog posts.

What I'm trying to do is hide the notification when the user clicks the "X" and keep it hidden with localStorage, but show the notification again if the post title within the notification is different.

HTML

```
<div class="notification">
  <div class="post-title">Blog Post Title</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".close").click(function(){
  $(".notification").hide();
  localStorage.setItem('newPost', $('.post-title').text());
});

if(localStorage.getItem('newPost') == $('.post-title').text()) {
  $(".notification").hide();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @peeebeee How do I show the notification again if the post title is different?

Comment: Run the JS again?

Comment: Work out the logic you're trying to implement first. Then the code will drop out.